# Facebook login in a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sdk, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails application using the Facebook flogin button with JavaScript.

**My code:***

```
<fb:login-button perms="email" onlogin="createFbSession();"></fb:login-button>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
</script>

<script>
    FB.init({
        appId:"xxxxxxx", cookie:true,
        status:true, xfbml:true
    });
    function createFbSession() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                window.location = "<%= fb_login_path %>";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

When I click on the flogin button, sometimes I receive the following error in the popup window:

> An error occurred. Please try again later.

What does it mean?

Comment: Same problem here. Worked fine for weeks then suddenly without any know reasons this is now happening in all browsers on all platforms I've tested.

Comment: I think your problem is not related to a certin app, it is a global facebook bug. it certinally has nothing to do with you using ruby since this is pure JS...

Comment: Unfortunately this "facebook bug" is been going on for days and as usual no one at Facebook's doing anything about it </rant>. So, if any one has any ideas on how to resolve this, earn 150 rep.

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes" ? Is it sometimes in exactly the sames conditions ??? Or it depends on the browser ..

Comment: Also, do you have an error code below ? Something like `API Error Code: 191`. Also are you using it always on the same URL ?

Comment: Hi. No, sometimes literally means sometimes. And sorry, no error codes that I'm aware of. Just the vague message "An error occurred. Please try again later.".

Answer (score 2):

You could use [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) which lets you use facebook/twitter/openid etc... in ruby without having to use a js library linked in from facebook.

Railscasts have a great episode on a [simple onmiauth setup](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) which is well worth a watch and because omniauth returns similar data for all providers just change twitter to facebook and you should be fine.

Omniauth also allows for multiple providers in the same login system, as some people (myself included) prefer to use twitter so enforced facebook login would put me off.

Answer (score 0):

When using the fb:login-button, for some reason, if you don't create it using the content_tag helper it breaks when rendered as html. In rails seems to work when rendered like this: `<%= content_tag("fb:login-button", "Log in", {:scope=>"email"}) %>`

Note: I'm using rails 3.1, I haven't tried that solution with previous versions.